# How to create a custom fileSystem and stateBackend by Overriding its default base classes in apache flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

-> I know it's quite a big process.

My objective is to read/write checkpoints directly from/to api without localFileSystem or hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a file system plugin. You can begin to learn about this by reading [Adding a new pluggable File System implementation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/filesystems/overview/#adding-a-new-pluggable-file-system-implementation) .

You won't need a custom state backend. Your choice of checkpoint storage is independent of the state backend -- any state backend can store its checkpoints in any file system.

Comment: If I didn't use customized state backend then how did flink knows which file system to use to read and  write checkpoints. 
Is there any way to specify the file system to statebackend?

Comment: The custom file system factory will declare the URI scheme under which the file system is being made available, and you'll configure Flink to use a URI with that scheme for checkpointing.

Comment: how to configure flink to use a URI with my FS's scheme for checkpointing?

Comment: state.checkpoints.dir: my-custom-scheme://checkpoint-location/